# how to detect input type using Angular based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

I want to detect `input` change when I enter `input` value, if `input` value equal to my condition it will `hide`/`show` `input` element,
this is what I had tried :

**ts File**

```
  isNoCard = false;

  onInputChange(inputValue: number): void {  
    if (inputValue === 7777) {
    this.isNoCard = true;
    }
 }
```

**html File**

```
<div *ngIf="!isNoCard">
<input (input)="onInputChange($event.target.value)" class="input--2" type="text" >
</div>

<div *ngIf="isNoCard">
<input class="input--1" type="text">
</div>
```

this is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qergs6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link, 
but when I had condition, it does not work. Is there any suggestion or guidance to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Its happening because the value which is being passed from HTML is `string`.

Handle it using angular way

```
<div *ngIf="!isNoCard">
  <input  [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange(data)" class="input--2" type="number" >
</div>
```

[Here is sample working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yq6jvx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Also, take a note that I have made `type="number"` because you are expecting the value as `number` inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing inputValue which of type string with number 7777.
Even though you have given type of inputValue parameter as number if you try to check the typeof that you would find it to be string.

```
console.log(typeof inputValue);
```

A simple solution in this case is to convert string to number by techniques like + operator, parseInt, etc.

If I try to do following it works -

```
if (+inputValue === 7777) {
  this.isNoCard = true;
}
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `===` operator to check the equality, which here will return `false`.
This happens because the input value is of type `string` and `7777` is a `number`.
You can either typecast the value or a simpler way to make this work is to use the `==` operator.

You can use simply the following code:

```
onInputChange(inputValue: number): void {  
    if (inputValue == 7777) {
    this.isNoCard = true;
    }
```

The `===` operator checks for both the values and type while the `==` operator checks for values only.